# How to store custom fields, their options and the selected option in a database

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to think of the best way to store the following in a PostgreSQL DB:

Custom fields,
The options for these custom fields,
The selected option for each custom field

Custom fields have a many-to-many relationship with another table- Tasks.
Each custom field can have only one selected option but can appear in more than one Task, all custom fields and selected options are just simple strings.
An option will always belong to only one custom field.

My thoughts on doing it are as follows.
Is this a good approach? Is there a better way?

Table: custom_field

Columns: name (string), selected_option_id (-> custom_field_option.id)

Table: custom_field_options

Columns: label (string), custom_field_id (-> custom_field.id)

I'm not sure about this because the same table (custom_field_options) has two relations with the same table (custom_fields)

Answer (score 0):

Many applications now default to using a tag model instead of individual custom fields with defined options.  Ignoring the merits of the differing approaches, here is what I have been using for the last twenty-five years:

```
create table task (
  task_id int not null generated always as identity primary key
  -- other columns go here
);

create table custom_field (
  custom_field_id int not null generated always as identity primary key,
  custom_field_name text not null unique
);

create table custom_field_option (
  custom_field_option_id int not null generated always as identity primary key,
  custom_field_id int not null references custom_field(custom_field_id),
  custom_field_value text not null,
  unique (custom_field_id, custom_field_value)
);

create table task_custom_field (
  task_custom_field_id int not null generated always as identity primary key,
  task_id int not null references task(task_id),
  custom_field_id int not null references custom_field(custom_field_id),
  custom_field_option_id int not null references custom_field_option(custom_field_option_id),
  unique (task_id, custom_field_id)
);
```

There is a slight denormalization since `custom_field_option` is never shared across different `custom_field` rows, but that denormalization allows using the `unique (task_id, custom_field_id)` constraint to limit only one option per custom field.

The names I used here are more verbose than I would use for the purposes of clarity.